# How to change background on every button of virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keydown

Can you help me with my virtual keyboard? I need to add keydown event with changing background into orange color on each button. in HTML I use buttons with classes `.letter` and `.symbol`.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log('Event', event)

    if(event.keyCode) {
      myButton.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';  
    }

})

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    myButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
 })
```

Comment: Please include your HTML too. Is there a specific reason you're trying to do this in JavaScript instead of CSS, which includes native focus/hover/active states?

Comment: well you need a way to match the key to the virtual key so that probably would be data attribute and a simple selector.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones how would "focus/hover/active" make any difference when using keypress events?

Comment: @epascarello it's not clear what they're trying to do without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so if they have a virtual keyboard and want to change the background color on hover/click/touch, those CSS properties allow that to easily be done. But if they're trying to change the background color when that key itself is pressed, then yes, they'll need to use JS to handle that. My point is that there's not enough info in the question to suggest a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a data attribute you can select the button based on the key pressed.

```js
function updateKeys(evt) {
  const btn = document.querySelector(`button[data-key="${evt.key}"]`);
  if (!btn) return;
  btn.classList.toggle('active', event.type === 'keydown');
}


window.addEventListener('keydown', updateKeys);
window.addEventListener('keyup', updateKeys);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button data-key="a">a</button>
<button data-key="s">s</button>
<button data-key="d">d</button>
<button data-key="f">f</button>
```

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer, but I would maybe add an if statement like **if(btn)** that way it only works if the key has a button and doesn't pop an error

Comment: It's a pity that this code doesn't work with button tag stylized with CSS. Why button tag ends with div?

Comment: @NadiaDen iThe issue is with your CSS having higher specificity so the color is not updated.